# Query - HashCode function explanation

Tags: java, eclipse, hashcode

I am having difficulty understanding how my professor`s hashcode function used in a past exam paper works. I kindly want to clarify the following:

**1- What type of hashing technique is used to detect the clashes and how does the 'HashCode' function handle the clashes?**

- I have tried the formula given below to find out, where the set is placed, but I have been coming out with different answers than the program (e.g h("cc") = 6 % 16 = 6 [16 the default capacity of a HashSet] while it is suppose to be 12 (double hashing is used to jump 6, it seems), but h("bb") is also 6). I am unsure of which type of hashing is used to overcome the clashes, is there any way of me to know?

---

**Question:**

Assume that a hashing function: () = . () % . , a load factor of 0.75 and separate changing are used in the program above. If inserting a new element will lead to a size/capacity ratio greater than the load factor, then the size of the hs is doubled and re-hashing is triggered before this new element is inserted. Draw diagrams that illustrate the capacity and contents of hs immediately after each statement that inserts a new element into hs is executed.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashStringDemo{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 HashSet<MyString> hs = new HashSet<>(2);
 MyString s1=new MyString("aa"),s2=new MyString("ab");
 MyString s3=new MyString("bb"),s4=new MyString("cc");

 hs.add(s1);
 hs.add(s2);
 hs.add(s3);
 hs.add(s4);
 }
}
class MyString{
 private String s;
 public MyString(String s){
 this.s=s;
 }
 public boolean equals(Object o){
 if (!(o instanceof MyString))
 return false;
 MyString s1 = (MyString)o;
 return s.equals(s1.s);
 }
 public int hashCode(){
 int sum=0;
 for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
 sum+=(s.charAt(i)-'a')*Math.pow(2,s.length()-i);
 }
 return sum;
 }
 public String toString(){ return s; }
}
```

Results (when calling the 'HashCode' function) using Eclipse IDE are:

```
aa : 0
ab : 2
bb : 6
cc : 12
```

Comment: (s.charAt(i) - 'a')  does not subtract 'a' it subtracts the ASCII value of 'a' which is 61, from the ascii value of the character at position i.
a = 0, b = 1, c = 2 etc; I guess your professor is assuming strings are made of letters from a - z. Without context that makes no sense, and results in negative numbers for some characters.

Comment: @teknopaul A clarification: `'a'` is 61 in hexadecimal (97 in decimal).